# Kubernetes says 'Deployment.apps "myDeploy" is invalid' after I deleted duplicated name of volumes

Tags: kubernetes

I had a Deployment, and a part of it was like this after a few update:

```yaml
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: myImage
        name: myImage
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /opt/data
      volumes:
      - name: data
        configMap:
          name: configmap-data
      - name: data
        configMap:
          name: configmap-data
```

then I found that the Deployment had duplicated volumes so I deleted one:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: myImage
        name: myImage
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /opt/data
      volumes:
      - name: data
        configMap:
          name: configmap-data
```

However, after that I could not apply/patch new Deployment. It said:

```
cannot patch "myDeploy" with kind Deployment: Deployment.apps "myDeploy" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "data"
```

I would like to solve this without downtime. How can I do this?

Comment: Normally it is not possible to have two `volumes` with the same `name`. If I try to create such a deployment I get an error: `The Deployment $DEPLOYMENT_NAME is invalid: spec.template.spec.volumes[1].name: Duplicate value: "data"`

Comment: Yes, you are right. The issue happened when I created a deployment with one volume and updated the deployment which was added the same name volume.